# span with background-image become bigger

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/r7d5fLe4/

```html
<span class="emote" style="background-image: url(https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v2/90076/default/dark/1.0);">
```

I have some same spans with background-image.

Why the images become a little bigger except the last one in a line?

Comment: i think it's because of your css code : background-size: contain;, try to change that

Comment: It is caused by the .img -> height, remove it and you see all are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing this on your `body` with CSS only. Putting it on a span could be problematic. Unless you want it to only be the background of an independent section, then I would use a `div` instead of `span`. (**See example two**). See the CSS changes in **example one**.

**example one**

```css
body {
    background-image: url('https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v2/90076/default/dark/1.0');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**example two**

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v2/90076/default/dark/1.0');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

All in all, I suggest a **higher-res** (larger) image for a background.